# Deleting multiple records in dynamo db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

can we delete multiple records in dynamo db only through range key?

I'm trying to do like this sql statement

**`delete from employee where employee_name='gopal';`**

so here the records with employee name `gopal` should get deleted

can we achieve same like this sql query in dynamo db?

Answer (score 8):

You would have to do a BatchWriteItem to delete your items.
[From the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html):

> BatchWriteItem performs put and delete

Comment: Good one. But you still need to query for the record and give their partition key to delete. Good find on BatchWriteItem, API name is not obvious to distinguish its operation.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check This query it's working with multiple data

```
const params = {TableName: "test"};

docClient.scan(params, (error, result) => {
        if (error) { console.log(error,"error scan"); }

        result.Items.forEach(function(item) {          
            docClient.delete({Key:{mainID: item.id},TableName:"test"}, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Delete fail");
                }
                console.log("Delete  Success");
            });
        });

});
```

Comment: This code will not delete the records in one go, it will make n numbers of call for n records.

Comment: FYI. The above code will do a table scan and delete all items one by one. Instead, you can delete and create the table. That's an easy and efficient operation. Also If there is any filter/query expression in params, then use BatchWriteItem. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the API, there is no Batch Delete for DynamoDB.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

You need to query the item and delete with their partition key.

I would recommend looking at ODM,

https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

to make the operations simpler.

Check out the sample calls for deletion,

```
Account.destroy('foo@example.com', function (err) {
  console.log('account deleted');
});

// Destroy model using hash and range key
BlogPost.destroy('foo@example.com', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
  console.log('post deleted')
});

BlogPost.destroy({email: 'foo@example.com', title: 'Another Post'}, function (err) {
  console.log('another post deleted')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kannaiyan thanks for your comments....

i found the solution with dynamoDB with java http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPICRUDExample.html

```
DeleteItemSpec deleteItemSpec = new DeleteItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("Id", 120)
                .withConditionExpression("#ip = :val").withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#ip", "InPublication"))
                .**withValueMap(new ValueMap()**.withBoolean(":val", false)).withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD);
```

fetching the records with key, value pair and storing it in "withValueMap(new ValueMap()" and this helps me.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this should work. The `.withConditionExpression()` is more likely about *Conditional write* feature in DynamoDB (check this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.DeleteData.html#SQLtoNoSQL.DeleteData.DynamoDB) where the deletion operation is still operating upon a single item, not range of items as original question asks. It just operates conditionally i.e. in your example, it would still *conditionally* delete record with primary key `id` 120 but it deletes only when the `InPublication` attribute has value of `false`.